# How to Replicate jQuery live() stopPropagation overrides with on()

Tags: jquery

I know this is a hackish question but basically I want to take advantage of one of the flaws with live() but do not want my code to get outdated by using it since it is deprecated.

Here is my situation:

I am using the Aloha editor in Wordpress. What I want to do is launch some extra functionality on images when the editor is active and an image is clicked.

the problem is that Aloha stops propagation of clicks on the link that is wrapped around the image. By using live() I can override this, where as if I use on() it obeys the stop propagation. I don't want to use deprecated code though, so does anyone know how I can make on() ignore this stop propagation as well?

I think there is a clue in the jQ notes for live()

> Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document.

So I think I need to do the same with on() but just can't work out how to do it. I guess I should probably make some changes to Aloha, but its so massive its just a bit intimidating.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `live` does obey `stopPropagation` so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.  http://jsfiddle.net/SnwrL/

Comment: As a guess, have you tried $(document).on("click", ".your-image", function()...)

Comment: Yeah, basically if I do this: jQuery('a.ice_image').live('click',function() {...
It works and if I do this
jQuery('a.ice_image').on('click',function() {...
Aloha blocks it. I am not sure if its stopPropagation or something similar since as I say the code for aloha is like 20Mb, so thats what I am asking really, is there a way of making on() misbehave like live() does so that I don't have to hack Aloha...

Comment: Ah man, I thought I had tried Mikes answer, but actually I have just tried again and it does work.
So the answer to my question is to attach the on() to the document in the first instance rather than the element itself as Mike has written above...

Answer (score 0):

This will override  event.stopPropagation()  `document.querySelector('#adv_search_i').addEventListener('click', function(e){
//code
});`